# Netsuite - How do you get saved search results into an scriptable email template from a workflow

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

So I am trying to create an email that will be sent out to customers with past due balances and details from a saved search proccessed by a workflow. I want to use a scriptable email template to create the layout of the information that we are sending to the customer. I did consider using the statement but as we want the data we are sending to be in the middle of the email it makes it a bit hard seeing the only settings for statements are above the email text or below.

My question is with in the scriptable template I have the following statement

```
<#if results?has_content>
<table style="width:100%; margin-top:10px;"><!-- Start items -->
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="6">Transaction Number</th>
    <th colspan="3">Invoice Date</th>
    <th colspan="3">Due Date</th>
    <th colspan="9">REFERENCE</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="4">Invoice Amount</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="4">Remaining Amount</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="4">Payment / Credit Memo</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<#list results as result>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="6">${result.tranid}</td>
    <td colspan="3">${result.trandate}</td>
    <td colspan="3">${result.duedate}</td>
    <td colspan="9">${result.otherrefnum}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4"><#if results.type == "CustInvc">${result.amount}</#if></td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${result.amountremaining}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4"><#if results.type == "CustCred">${result.amount}</#if></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</#list></table>
</#if>
```

But when the scheduled workflow fires off and sends the email I do not get the table as it seems the results do not have any content. Can this be accomplished this way?

The reason this is not scripted "as I would rather have it that way" is because when I ran my test scripts they timed out because the amount of data being gathered.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can only source the record object in a scriptable email template.